# why VS is not Throwing an exception when trying to check if null string contains a string

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

isnt this scenario should throw an exception? 
im passing a string type variable that has a value of nothing to returenComboSelectedIndex() function in order to check if it containes other string, and there is no exception.

tryed to debug it with breakpoint and instead of raising an exception it moves to Dispose sub in a some **other** class that exist in the file and then to other thread that running on the background(why?) and not raising the "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*" exception like it should.

**is there something wrong with the debug properties on my vs?
am i missing something else?**

Thank you

```
Private Sub showPredictionStructure(ByVal existingInDb As Boolean, _
                                    ByVal pStruct As ProjectData.PredictedProjectEnding _
                                    , Optional ByVal integrationStruct As ProjectData.integrationData = Nothing)

comboIntagrationProffesional.SelectedIndex = returenComboSelectedIndex(Nothing, comboIntagrationProffesional)

End Sub

    Private Function returenComboSelectedIndex(ByVal itm As String, ByVal combo As ComboBox) As Integer

        For i = 0 To combo.Items.Count - 1
            If itm.Contains(combo.Items(i).ToString) Or combo.Items(i).ToString.Contains(itm) Then
                Return i
            End If
        Next

        Return -1

    End Function
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the described behavior.  It throws a `NullReferenceException` for me.

Comment: I suspect that if you create a *minimal* example you'll find that you can't reproduce this behaviour. What does the *rest* of the code do? What happens if you continue debugging? Does the application crash? Is `Dispose` called because the application is terminating due to the unhandled error?

Comment: Hi allredy tryed to create a minimal example and in that case the exception  is raised like it should.  I know that is wierd behavior but i checked it more than one time.  What happened in later stage of running is that the sub that calles showPredictionStructure()  is exiting after the call and the code keeps running until there is other exception that caused by the that.  Sorry for spelling and mistakes im on cell phone now

Comment: You likely have a Try..Catch somewhere catching the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Debug >>> Windows >>> Exception Settings
```

Check:

```
C++ Exceptions
Common Language Runtime Exception
```

If they are already checked please check that additional actions are not set to:

> "Continue when unhandled in user code"

Comment: tnx, i tryed to make some changes in exception settings (i have vs 2012 so its a little bit different properties menu) according to what you wrote also according to MSDN documents but the problem still exist. it is more reasonable its related to try catch somewhere because when i made a minimal example the exception was thrown, so i have commented all the try catches related but still no change...

Comment: then do ctrl+f and write catch and search for it. There should never be empty catch so this must be writing to some log. If they are empty search stackoverflow for good way to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a Try..Catch somewhere catching the exception.

Try resetting your exception settings by doing what @Claudius said.

Do you get any errors from VS telling you your debug symbols are different from the code your debugging? Try cleaning your entire project, rebuilding and then debug it with a breakpoint.